# cannot read properties of null (reading map)

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Intento cargar un gráfico, pero no puedo cargarlo.

este es el error que aparece en la consola:

[image: error en consola]

component ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDatosGrafico()

  }




 getDatosGrafico() {
    this.graficoService.getCantidadOperadoresBrechas(189)
      .then(res => {
        this.graficoBrecha = res;
        this.buildData(this.graficoBrecha);
        console.log(res);
        console.log(this.buildData);
      });
  }

  buildData(graficoBrecha: GraficoBrecha[]) {
    graficoBrecha.map(x => {
      let perfil = x.perfil.toLowerCase();
      perfil= perfil[0].toUpperCase() + perfil.substring(1);
      this.basicData.labels.push(perfil);
    })
    this.basicData.datasets.push(
      {
        label: 'Cantidad de operarios con brechas',
        backgroundColor: '#f60707',
        data: graficoBrecha.map(x => x.operadores_brechas)
      })
    this.datosCargados = true;
  }
```

services:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el grafico no carga la informacion y sale que no puede leer la propiedad map

uso web api c#

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. El idioma oficial del sitio es el castellano, por favor traduce tu pregunta o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: hola ya cambie el idioma, me podria volver abrir la pregunta?

Comment: La respuesta es obvia de todas maneras, además que viene indicada en el error que muestras... Estás usando `.map()` sobre un `null`. Null no tiene métodos. Lo que te ha dado es el clásico null pointer exception de java, pero en typescript. Mira por qué tu dato no tiene valor, o asegúrate de que lo tiene antes de usarlo.